# Java JVM-wide settings

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am looking for a list of JVM wide system parameters. These could be set by calling `System.setProperty` or by calling a static method defined in the Platform. The purpose is to have a list of method calls that should be avoided from applications running in a container. Because those methods change a system wide parameter, they could have unpredictable effects on other applications. This could be enforced by setting appropriate permissions at runtime or having findbug rules at build time.

As a start, I have:

- Locale.setDefault(Locale newLocale)
- TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone zone)
- Java net system properties: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/net/properties.html

More?

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7616206/418556).

Answer (score 1):

The timezone, locale and system properties you mention are static variables and not scoped by the JVM, but rather by the **Class** object representing the containing class.

**Class** objects are scoped by the [ClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) which loaded it.

This is for example how a servlet container like Tomcat can have multiple web-services running in the same JVM but with different default timezone and locale.

Take a look at Tomcat's class loader how-to: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html