# Java : Audio capture device listing using Java Media Framework

Tags: java, audio, record, jmf, javasound

```
import javax.media.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ListCaptureDevices {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Vector info = CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList(null);
        if (info == null)
            System.out.println("No Capture devices known to JMF");
        else {
            System.out.println("The following " + info.size()
                    + " capture devices are known to the JMF");
            for (int i = 0; i < info.size(); i++)
                System.out
                        .println("\t" + (CaptureDeviceInfo) info.elementAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Above is the code to list the capture devices. It does not return `null` vector but still it print the size of the vector as `0` and says no devices are found. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please format code samples.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the message posting/editing form.

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to use JMF to discover the sound capture devices.  See the `MediaTypes` class on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7616206/418556) for example source.