# How to distinguish between DirectAudioDevice and PortMixer mixers?

Tags: java, audio, microphone, javasound, mixer

I am enumerating mixers with `AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()`. I found that returning mixers are sometimes duplicated. Investigation showed, that 4 mixers returned are of class `DirectAudioDevice` and 6 mixers are of class `PortMixer`. Both classes are undocumented classes of Java API.

I wish to present a user with only one copy of each microphone, while in my case they returned both as `DirectAudioDevice` and `PortMixer`.

So, the question is: what is the difference between these two classes and how to distinguish them at runtime?

**UPDATE**

I found that `DirectAudioDevice` version of each microphone returns nothing on `getLine(Port.Info.MICROPHONE)` while return one line on `getTargetLineInfo()`, while `PortMixer` versions of microphones returns something on `getLine(Port.Info.MICROPHONE)`, while return both target and source lines, while target one is entitled "loudness"...

Comment: See the **[Media](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7616206/418556)** based source in "List of useful environment settings in Java" for code to help you trawl through the JavaSound abilities.