# List of all system properties supported by a JRE

Tags: java

Yesterday I came across a system property in Java `-Djsse.enableCBCProtection=false` which was added in JDK 6u30. I never knew about this till yesterday.

So can anyone tell me where I can find the list of system properties supported in a Java version along with its meaning?

Comment: See also [List of useful environment settings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7616206/418556).

Comment: *"along with its meaning?"*  The names are designed with the intention(1) of being 'intuitively obvious' as soon as you understand each word.  1) Whether the intent is achieved, is open to debate.

Comment: yes, but `user.home` is not obvious on Windows platform...

Comment: You're assuming that such a list exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not a single place with such a list. System properties are used all over the place by various parts of the Java environment, so you have to consult the documentation for the part you are using to see about their properties. For example the Java networking documentation describes several properties used by the URLConnection mechanism.

Comment: I know. But in every jre version there may be an addition. Where I can find its details.

Comment: You have to look at the release notes or documentation for the component you are interested in. There is no central list.

Comment: I checked but not able to find it in release notes.

Comment: Then you have to look in the documentation.

Comment: can you send me the link of documentation for jre6 any update?

Comment: @Newbie - have you tried Google?  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/releasenotes-136954.html

Comment: Yes.But i did not get details about the system property I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Dude, Google the property itself, I just did and about out the meaning of it quite quickly.

Answer (score 8):

Use this to get list of all supported properties.

```
    Properties props =  System.getProperties();
    System.out.println(props);
```

Also see [here](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/io/30properties_and_preferences/40sysprops/10sysprop.html), most are mentioned .

Comment: I am looking for a place where I can get the list with its meaning. How exactly this affects my java program.

Comment: few links provide meaning of some standard properties. there may be some other place where we can get all. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/properties.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/net/properties.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/env/source.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html
http://www.javafundu.com/2009/12/jndi-environment-properties.html

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't (after all this time) a command line switch to java that can do this. Something like `-verbose:properties`.