# Is it possible to capture the playing audio with Java?

Tags: java, audio, capture, outputstream, javasound

I was wondering if it's possible to capture playing audio on the audio output hardware with a simple Java program, and then write it to an outputstream for example.

Is it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java, how do I record the sound output that is going to the speakers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157289/in-java-how-do-i-record-the-sound-output-that-is-going-to-the-speakers)

Comment: This was asked literally yesterday.

Comment: Different question (at least as asked): yesterday's asks about recording what is output by the current app, this asks about recording what is going to the hardware, possibly by other apps.

Answer (score 0):

If your desire is to record the output of all programs to a given audio device using a java app, like audiohijackpro, the short answer is no, this is not possible without native code. It is, in fact, quite difficult to do in any language. As far as I know, no platform makes this easy.

On some environments, there is a workaround, eg, http://cycling74.com/soundflower-landing-page/, but it requires that your end user cooperate.

Comment: I'm looking for a native solution but one with a command line interface. Do you know one ?

Comment: @coding_idiot depends on your platform and audio API. The short answer is probably not.

Comment: but there are large number of softwares that are able to record speaker output, anyways, I'll keep looking.