# Record audio from application

Tags: java, audio, javasound

How to record audio from Java application program?

I'm from Ethiopia and computer science student, am trying to develop Java application for Ethiopian's traditional music instruments just like simulation app. and this application has record functionality.  But I have difficulties to record the sounds that come from my music instrument application while the user plays it.

Comment: *"but i got difficulties to record the sounds"*  What difficulties?  What have you tried & what happened?

Comment: Please read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/package-summary.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/sound

Answer (score 2):

First of all: what have you tried so far?

I assume you're trying to capture audio using a microphone. If so, I suggest you try using JavaSound (javax.sound) - see the Oracle documentation for it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/package-summary.html).

A couple of other tutorials for you to explore (in case you haven't yet):

- [Oracle Docs - Trail: Sound](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/)
- [Oracle Docs - Capturing Audio](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html)

Also, [this website](http://www.jsresources.org/examples/audio_playing_recording.html) has a few examples of usages of JavaSound.

Give it a go and see how far you can get - if you still get stuck, please post the code of what you've got so far and we'll try helping further.

Good luck!

Comment: :) thank you for your suggestion! what am trying to do is,i dont want to capture audio using microphone instead i need to record audio that comes out from the specific speaker line that comes out for my application.

Comment: I see! Well, the Oracle Docs I suggested would still be applicable, but have a look at this Java Tips tutorial as well: http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.sound/capturing-audio-with-java-sound-api.html - if you could post any code you've got so far, that would allow me/other people to help you out further.

Comment: please can u help me how to post the code,i cant post it i mean it takes a lot of character above the limit (am just a beginner to post on this site.:)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to record the output of another program with Java.

Here is an answer to a related question:

[Is it possible to capture the playing audio with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168465/is-it-possible-to-capture-the-playing-audio-with-java/11170689)