# how to get system information using java (Applet)?

Tags: java, applet, system

I want to get some specific system information such as; processor speed, processor family, OS version (ex: "5.1 Service pack 1"), color depth, system directory.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/using-java-to-get-os-level-system-information

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7616206/418556).

Comment: Of course, getting this type of information will require a trusted applet.

Comment: i read all about System.getProperties() and the previous questions. @RussellGutierrez However, there is no answer to my question. I want to get computer's color depth, Processor speed(xxx GHZ), Processor name (like Computer->Right Click->Properties window) and the name of OS(Not just Windows 7 but also Windows 7 Service Pack 1 etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.getProperties()` which returns `java.util.Properties` Object. This contains all the system properties. Have a look the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29) for more and see all the needed properties are available for you.