# how do I get Mixer channels layout in java

Tags: java, audio, javasound, mixer, channel

I thought I can find anything on this great site but now I seem to face the issue with no answer :) Please help!

Thing is, I need to play up to 6 different wav files with 1 channel each into 6 channels supported by system mixer (left, right, surround left, etc).

Using 6 different SourceDataLines looks logical but from what I see, Mixer cannot do per-sample synchronisation for them, so I came up with interleaving them in separate thread and use only one SourceDataLine to play it. It works fine for two channels, left and right but for more channels I need to know precise channels layout (may be different on diff. system, and sound cards). I thought that one of system Mixers (I have two: "linear input" and "java sound system mixer") might have this metadata but I can't find it.

Does anybody know how to get this info?

Thanks.

Comment: Java sound only supports up to stereo, everything else is produced by the native sound software and hardware.

Answer (score 3):

My friend and I just figured out that java7 sound system supports 6 channels and all the variants of their using with different bits, etc.

Here is the code to list what your java can do:

```
        Mixer.Info[] mi = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
        for (Mixer.Info info : mi) {
            System.out.println("info: " + info);
            Mixer m = AudioSystem.getMixer(info);
            System.out.println("mixer " + m);
            Line.Info[] sl = m.getSourceLineInfo();
            for (Line.Info info2 : sl) {
                System.out.println("    info: " + info2);
                Line line = AudioSystem.getLine(info2);
                if (line instanceof SourceDataLine) {
                    SourceDataLine source = (SourceDataLine) line;

                    DataLine.Info i = (DataLine.Info) source.getLineInfo();
                    for (AudioFormat format : i.getFormats()) {
                        System.out.println("    format: " + format);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This is output from my macbook pro with usb connected external sound card:

```
info: Default Audio Device, version Unknown Version
mixer com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice@67310bf
    info: interface SourceDataLine supporting 14 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
    format: PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big-endian
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, mono, 3 bytes/frame, little-endian
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, mono, 3 bytes/frame, big-endian
    format: PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, little-endian
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, big-endian
    format: PCM_SIGNED 48000.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    format: PCM_SIGNED 48000.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
    info: interface Clip supporting 14 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
info: Built-in Input, version Unknown Version
mixer com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice@2edf98c4
info: Built-in Output, version Unknown Version
mixer com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice@59a683e6
    info: interface SourceDataLine supporting 14 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
    format: PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big-endian
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, mono, 3 bytes/frame, little-endian
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, mono, 3 bytes/frame, big-endian
    format: PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, little-endian
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, big-endian
    format: PCM_SIGNED 48000.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    format: PCM_SIGNED 48000.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
    info: interface Clip supporting 14 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
info: SB X-Fi Surround 5.1 Pro, version Unknown Version
mixer com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice@431d9f05
    info: interface SourceDataLine supporting 20 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
    format: PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big-endian
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, mono, 3 bytes/frame, little-endian
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, mono, 3 bytes/frame, big-endian
    format: PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, little-endian
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, big-endian
    format: PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, 6 channels, 6 bytes/frame, 
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, 6 channels, 6 bytes/frame, 
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, 6 channels, 12 bytes/frame, little-endian
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, 6 channels, 12 bytes/frame, big-endian
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, 6 channels, 18 bytes/frame, little-endian
    format: PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 24 bit, 6 channels, 18 bytes/frame, big-endian
    format: PCM_SIGNED 48000.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    format: PCM_SIGNED 48000.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
    info: interface Clip supporting 20 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
info: SB X-Fi Surround 5.1 Pro, version Unknown Version
mixer com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice@4db323af
info: Port Built-in Input, version Unknown Version
mixer com.sun.media.sound.PortMixer@4b743fba
    info: Built-in Input source port
info: Port Built-in Output, version Unknown Version
mixer com.sun.media.sound.PortMixer@45d1edcc
info: Port SB X-Fi Surround 5.1 Pro, version Unknown Version
mixer com.sun.media.sound.PortMixer@59530fe3
info: Port SB X-Fi Surround 5.1 Pro, version Unknown Version
mixer com.sun.media.sound.PortMixer@5c382de5
    info: SB X-Fi Surround 5.1 Pro source port
```

Comment: See also the `MediaTypes` source on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7616206/418556) to "List of useful environment settings in Java".

Answer (score 3):

Yes, its an old question but since i was searching to get all the channels, depths and so on i decided to write a small debug method which is usefull if you like to see more details and would like to use java 8 streams :-)

Enjoy:

```
//filter may be all if you want to include microphone 
 public void getDeviceInfos(String filter) {

            Stream
                    .of(AudioSystem.getMixerInfo())
                    .forEach(info -> {
                        System.out.println("Mixer Name: " + info.getName());
                        System.out.println("Mixer Description: " + info.getDescription());
                        System.out.println("Mixer Vendor: " + info.getVendor());

                        Mixer m = AudioSystem.getMixer(info);

                        Stream
                                .of(Arrays.asList(m.getSourceLineInfo()), filter.equals("record") ? Arrays.asList(m.getTargetLineInfo()) : null)
                                .flatMap(List::stream)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                                .forEach(lineInfo -> {
                                    System.out.println("    info: " + lineInfo);
                                    try {
                                        Line line = AudioSystem.getLine(lineInfo);
                                        if (line instanceof SourceDataLine || line instanceof TargetDataLine) {

                                            Arrays.asList(((DataLine.Info) line.getLineInfo()).getFormats()).forEach(format -> {
                                                System.out.println("Channels: " + format.getChannels());
                                                System.out.println("Size in Bits: " + format.getSampleSizeInBits());
                                                System.out.println("Frame Rate: " + format.getFrameRate());
                                                System.out.println("Frame Size: " + format.getFrameSize());
                                                System.out.println("Encoding: " + format.getEncoding());
                                                System.out.println("Sample Rate: " + format.getSampleRate());

                                            });
                                        }
                                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                                        ex.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                });
                    });

    }
```