# .getSourceLines() always returns 0

Tags: java, audio, javasound, mixer

I have a mixer and I want to gather information on its source lines. My code is as follows.

```
myMixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[i]); // index through all list of mixers
Line[] lines = myMixer.getSourceLines();
System.out.println(lines.length);
```

In the code, I cycle through every mixer on my computer and then I try to get a list of all the source lines. However none of the source lines are open to the mixer. How do I access these lines? `System.out.println(lines.length)` always prints 0.

Comment: See the [`MediaTypes`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585699/list-of-useful-environment-settings-in-java/7616206#7616206) source on this thread for an overview.  Note that Java Sound is hit and miss.  It might be that machine does not register any microphones.

Comment: I've noticed this. Java does not work consistently on other platforms. Windows works like a charm while linux is giving me problems. I haven't had the chance to test on Mac, however Mac is like linux so this makes me nervous.

Comment: Java Sound is about as unreliable on Mac. as on *nix.  :(

Comment: That's ironic since I began developing in Java since its a cross-platform language. Apparently its not that easy, at least it's free to develop with.