# How to get List of Audio Soundcards and Drivers of PC using Java

Tags: java, audio, driver, javasound, soundcard

How can I get the list of Soundcards and Audio Drivers of PC in java. OS, I am currently using is Windows.
I would be grateful if I could get some assistance in this regards.

Comment: Java doesn't provide a way to get low level OS details like this without using something like JNI. The Java sound API has `AudioSystem.getMixerInfo` which lists the Java sounds mixers that are available.

Comment: @greg-449 is there any opensource java API which could help me achieve the desired manipulation?

Comment: I don't use Windows so I don't know what might be available.

Comment: See also the `MediaTypes` code on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7616206/418556).

Answer (score 0):

May be here... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing.html

```
Mixer.Info[] infos = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
    for (int i = 0; i < infos.length; i++) {
        Mixer.Info info = infos[i];

        System.out.println(String.format("Name [%s], description - [%s]\n", info.getName(), info.getDescription()));
        System.out.println(info.getDescription());
    }
```